# Can we reopen this question? [Subtitle - He asked can we reopen the question?]

Tags: discussion

In the quest for keeping this site in the best possible shape for our readers, this question ["Do you know where's Linda?" vs "Do you know where Linda is?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36623/do-you-know-where-is-linda-vs-do-you-know-where-linda-is/36640#36640), quite reasonably, got closed as a duplicate.

Now on the surface it might look as though this question is just about the difference between subordinate and sentential interrogatives. On close inspection though, it isn't really. It is about what are sometimes (erroneously) called *citation questions*. I use these quite a lot. Here are some from my own posts on another site:

- So now the burning question is what is the subject of this existential sentence?
- Do you know what's the problem?

Here you can see subordinate interrogative forms with subject-auxiliary inversion as in proper questions. This is one of the main issues in the OP's question. The OP doesn't ask about questions versus indirect questions, or sentential questions versus interrogative clauses and so forth - which is what the linked-to question is all about: ["How it works?" vs. "How does it work?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17778/how-it-works-vs-how-does-it-work/17796?noredirect=1#comment69048_17796)

While citation questions may be of marginal acceptability in standard English ( - I note though that no-one blinks when I use them in my post). They are still of some importance to learners who are going to encounter them and wonder what exactly is going on. For this reason, I think it would be very useful to reopen the 'dupe'. Can we do this please? (I personally don't have enough rep for a reopen vote).

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Good point - and a good opportunity to distinguish some subtleties of register.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks! During the course of the morning, I seem to have got the requisite amount of rep to reopen vote! The question's now open again. Thanks, because I think it's useful as you say. The question now is, what should I do with *this* question here on meta? Should I leave it here (might be good for directing people to if they close vote it again) or should I delete it (because it's now a little redundant for readers)? Any advice? (and then I'll leave you in peace!)

Comment: I went ahead and voted to reopen, but I do think some of the commentary belongs in chat and not as comments on the answer.