# What's the standard process for getting a closed question reopened again?

Tags: discussion, reopen

If I see a question that's been closed and IMO deserves reopening, what's the intended process for getting it reopened again, both when I think it was wrongly closed, and when it has since been improved to meet the standard?

In searching Meta, I've found [requests to open particular closed questions](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/this-question-needs-reopening-please), I've seen it implied that [merely editing a closed question triggers a reopen vote](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1244/editing-a-question-to-trigger-reopen-vote), and I've checked the topics in [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help), but I haven't found anything that definitively states how the procedure is designed to happen.

Comment: 5 users need to agree to cast their vote to reopen a closed question.

Comment: How to achieve this can depend on several factors. But the most efficacious way is when the OP  edits their post that addresses the reasons their Q was closed. This means adding a little research (e.g a dictionary definition) , clarifying a point  or even fixing bad spelling and punctuation. When a closed post has been edited it automatically enters the **reopen review queue** where reviewers decide it's "fate".

Comment: Actually the procedure is explained rather well in this extract: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: This article may help https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions and here is a pretty good example of a request to reopen a question https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1238/9161

Comment: You may also find this "product discovery" post on Meta relevant [Changing the question reopening experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367231/273494)

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article contains all the details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions

But **tl;dr:**

Any closed question gets reopened when:

- one moderator votes to reopen it, OR
- when a question reaches 5 reopen votes (only users with 3,000+ rep can vote)

There is also a reopen vote queue where designated candidates for reopening are listed. A closed question enters this queue either when

- one 3,000+ user votes to reopen it, OR
- someone edits the question within 5 days of it being closed

You can bring attention to a question by posting it here in Meta.